# Distinguish different droppable elements (jQuery drag & drop)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drag, interactive

I am creating an interactive screen for an academy assignment and I'm kind of stuck  at the moment.

We have 2 dropzones and 3 droppable elements. Whenever droppable element a is dragged to a dropzone, it now shows the same content when droppable element b is dropped. (dropping it adds a class which add display block to the hidden content to show up)

Is there a way to distinguish the droppable element so we can pop up different content linked to different droppable elements?

```
$(function() {
$( "#draggable1" ).draggable({ revert: true });
    $( "#draggable2" ).draggable({ revert: true });
    $( "#draggable3" ).draggable({ revert: true });

$( "#dropzone1" ).droppable({
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( ".content" ).css({display: "block"});
             $( "#dropzone1" ).hide();
  }
});
$( "#dropzone2" ).droppable({
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( ".content" ).css({display: "block"});
             $( "#dropzone2" ).hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: kindly check this https://jsfiddle.net/zjfyjae9/

Comment: updated https://jsfiddle.net/zjfyjae9/1/

Comment: Thanks alot, I'll look into it right away.

Answer (score 0):

are u looking for something like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/avq1wkp5/

```
$( "#draggable1" ).draggable({ revert: true });
$( "#draggable2" ).draggable({ revert: true });
$( "#draggable3" ).draggable({ revert: true });

$( "#dropzone1" ).droppable({
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#content1" ).show();
            $( "#content2" ).hide();
   }      
});

$( "#dropzone2" ).droppable({
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#content2" ).show();
            $( "#content1" ).hide();
  }
});
```

or an improved version

https://jsfiddle.net/avq1wkp5/1/